# View Issue - Unique Permissions AND List View Thresholds at the same time

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, list-view-threshold, security-trimming

I have a list with around 5500 items in it currently, it grows by around 1000 items per month.

I have folders enabled for this list, there are around 500 folders in total, each of those folders has unique permissions. Each folder will contain only a small number of items, no more than 26 per year per folder.

I have a view that shows all items without folders, grouped on a metadata field for each item. The average user only has permission to somewhere between 1-12 folders, however as soon as we breached the 5000 item limit for the whole list the view stopped showing any items with an ID greater than 5000. The users DO NOT get the list threshold error. The view shows up normallyswith a small number of items from the folder that user can see, but simply doesn't include the most recent items in that folder.

It seems like the security trimming does not count as a filter.

Has anyone run into this before? Any suggestions other than just "figure out a different filter value"? I don't have a good field to filter on unfortunately. I was relying on the folder permissions to be the filter.

I'm using entirely different views with appropriate filters for the users that need to see all the records in the list, it just doesn't apply to the average user of the list.

Comment: If you are applying filters in the list view, [add indexing on the columns](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) you used for filtering. Also, make sure the the filtered view returns less than 5000 items in each view (if you are using classic experience list view pages). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That is not helpful at all, you didn't even read the question and just copy pasted the standard view information.

Comment: Are there any default filters applied to the list? Indexed columns that Ganesh suggested might actually help you out here. 

Using F12 developer tools - are there any console errors appering when a user access the view?